# How to add variable endings? Swift

Tags: swift, variables

Im looking for a solution in Swift.
I have a counter variable "counter" which adds 1 every time the func is called. Now with every new calling of the func, another variable should get called, like:

```
func questions() {                                                         
  counter += 1                                                     
  labelQuestion.text = question"counter" -> question0 -> question1 -> ...
}
```

How I can do that?!
Thanks already for answers!

Comment: It sounds like you might be looking for an `Array`. Are you familiar with those? Then, you can do something like `question[counter]` and get a reference to an item at a certain position within array.

Comment: @jnpdx well, wasnt thinking of an array, but you are actually right, that would solve my problem either, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

May be use a didSet property observer on counter :

```
var counter: Int = 0 {
    didSet {
        labelQuestion.text = set the new question 
    }
}

func nextQuestion() {
    counter += 1
}
```